# EntityFramework DBContext FirstOrDefault closes connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection

I'm somewhat of a junio programmer, so I need to understand this. I'm using EntityFramework 5. We have a repository class implemented, which inherits DbContext. When calling the FirstOrDefault method, if there is no value to be returned, EntityFramework closes the connection. This makes the code brake, complaining that dbContext.Database.Connection.ServerVersion is null. In fact the connections state is "Closed". I'm actually injecting the repository to test a service, without using Ninject or the like. Is this why this is happening ?

This is where I inject the repository:

```
IRepository<stock_queues> repo = new DbContextRepositoryEcom<stock_queues>(new DbContextFactory<eComEntities>(new eComEntities()));

        StockFlashService service = new StockFlashService(repo, new PartsService(), new UserService());

        service.AddToStockFlashQueue("asfsdfgvsdf");
```

and this is where I acotually run the code (in a different project):

```
  public StockFlashService(IRepository<stock_queues> queues, IPartsService parts, IUserService users)                     
    {
        this._QueuesRepo = queues;          
        this._PartsService = parts;
        _UsersService = users;
      //  userId = _UsersService.GetUser().UserId;
        userId = 30; //FOR TESTING ONLY !!
    }

 public void AddToStockFlashQueue(string key)
    {            
        stock_queues sq = new stock_queues();
        sq.partnumber = key;
        sq.userID = userId;
        sq.timestamp = DateTime.Now;

        // Adds new entry to Stock Flash queue (if required)
        stock_queues part;
        int count = _QueuesRepo.Count();
        if (_QueuesRepo.Count() > 0)
        {               
            part = _QueuesRepo.FirstOrDefault(f => f.userID == sq.userID && f.partnumber == sq.partnumber); // THIS IS WERE IT ALL BRAKES

        }
}
```

I'm using a console app to test the service and inject the dependencies. The project were this service is hosted (not a windows / web service but actually the logic that does all the magic) is an MVC app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirstorDefault returns null when there are no values - as in ur case. Check for null first and then assign it to 'part'